# Complex Mysql query to fetch information

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

I am currently working on a project to I fetch some information from an API and store it in a database. The table structure looks something like this:

```
id      ident aircraft_type  origin  destination  timestamp        departure_time
1      AWE1843      A321      KATL     KCLT    2012-10-04 10:46:34  2012-10-04 10:01:00 
2      ASQ5758      CRJ2      KATL     KIAD    2012-10-04 10:51:11  2012-10-04 09:40:00     
3      AAL2404      B738      KLAX     KDFW    2012-10-04 10:46:13  2012-10-04 08:23:00     
4      AAL2400      B738      KLAX     KDFW    2012-10-04 09:54:13  2012-10-04 07:31:00     
5      UAL912       B752      KLAX     KJFK    2012-10-04 10:19:24  2012-10-04 05:39:00
6      DAL1162      B752      KLAX     KCLT    2012-10-04 09:38:00  2012-10-04 04:44:30
```

The six rows are for demonstration purposes; I have around 500 rows of such data. The application I am working on will ask the user to provide the two origin points and will provide the user with all the common destinations between those two origins.

For example, if a user enters "KATL" and "KLAX" as origin airports, the query displays the common destination between the two origins which is "KCLT".

I tried different approaches to fix the issue but cannot get the desired functionality achieved. I tried joins and different ActiveRecord methods to no use.

Comment: can there be two destinations as answer

Comment: You need to provide at least a skeleton example of the code you're trying to fix. This doesn't seem complicated, so it's not clear where your issue is.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh: I need to get all the destinations between the two origin points. It can be 2,3 or even 100. Its a simple equation actually i.e. All the destinations from two origins.

Comment: you mean all common destinations? and two points are fixed, they can't be three

Comment: @tadman: I am not struggling with the code.I am actually looking to get all common destinations in the table between two origins.I have no problem executing raw sql or ActiveRecord method to get the information. The problem is I do not know how to do it.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh: There are always going to be two origin points provided by user and we need to spit out all the common destinations between the two origins in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will work it will give you both tables though, you can use s.* or e.* to pick specific table if you need to:

```
select * from (select * from flights where origin = 'KATL') s
inner join (select * from flights where origin = 'KLAX') e
on e.destination = s.destination;
```

If you just want to display destinations:

```
select distinct s.destination from (select * from flights where origin = 'KATL') s
inner join (select * from flights where origin = 'KLAX') e
on e.destination = s.destination;
```

Comment: Thanks it returned exactly what I was wanting to return.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your model name as Path

```
path = Path.where("origin in (#{ORIGIN1},#{ORIGIN2})")
path.uniq.collect{ |p| p if path.count(p) > 1}.compact
```

this will give you all the destinations for given two origin without complex mysql query

thanks

Comment: This will not work, p could belong to only origin2 yet there might be multiple flights so count will be > 1, and it will be returned as a match while it is not. "Complex" query is what you want in this case, if you have 1,000,000 paths for example, you don't what to load them into memory, loop through them collecting counts, uniq, compact etc.